# MySql ERROR: 1525: Incorrect DATE value: ''

Tags: mysql

I have installed a script but it gives me this error

QUERY:

[error mysql]

```
SELECT data,
       visits 
FROM php_stats_daily 
WHERE data!=NOW() 
AND data!='' 
ORDER BY visits ASC LIMIT 1
```

> MySql ERROR: 1525: Incorrect DATE value: ''

database is

`php_stats_daily`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS php_stats_daily (
  data date NOT NULL default '2000-01-01',
  hits int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  visits int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  no_count_hits int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  no_count_visits int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  rets int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (data)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: An empty string isn't a valid date literal. Maybe you want `IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: We already know the `data` can't be null - it's defined that way in the table.  So just drop the whole `AND data!='' `  Like Sticky says, don't conflate "zero values" *or* invalid values with NULL.

Comment: Maybe you want `where data > '2000-01-01' and data < now()`?

Comment: `data` column is DATE datatype - hence it cannot contain empty string, and comparing with empty string makes no sense. At the same time this empty string cannot be converted to DATETIME which causes an error. PS. What do you want to test in your query?